# Cannot access the scrollToIndex() method in React Native using the useRef hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to access the `scrollToIndex()` method or `scrollToItem()` method from FlatList using the `useRef` hook in a functional component.  I want to be able to use `flatListRef.current.ScrollToIndex()` in my component, similar to the way a class-based component uses `this.flatListRef.ScrollToIndex()`:

```
 const flatListRef = useRef(React.createRef)
 <FlatList 
    data={items}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.card}
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}  
    ref={flatListRef}                      
/>
```

console.logging `flatListRef.current` doesn't show the aforementioned methods I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to create a ref with `createRef`, you can just use `useRef()`. Another important thing is to use `scrollToIndex` correctly. See [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex) and the code below.

**Code:**

```
const CustomFlatList = () => {
  const flatListRef = useRef(); // useRef 
  return (
    <View>
    <FlatList 
        data={items}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={{width: 100}}> {item.id} </Text> }
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.card}
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}  
        ref={flatListRef} // create ref                
    />
     <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: 4, animated: true })}>
     <Text> ScrollToIndex </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Working Example:**

https://snack.expo.io/B1rfdbsuS